# Write Secret Shared Data onto Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, transactions, cpp-ethereum

What would be an approach to do the following:

1) Secret Share data provided from a file

2) Publish the secret shared data onto an Ethereum instance (aleth/geth)

3) Be able to retrieve and reconstruct the data from the blockchain instance?

I have thought about creating and deploying a smart contract or submitting a transaction but am not sure if there are existing programs that serve the purpose described above.

Comment: I don't understand your question completely, but check parity secret store and private transactions

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - by secret shared data, I meant we use a Shamir secret sharing scheme on a data set, and then store this on ethereum, and then be able to read back and reconstruct the original message/data. Are there existing tools that are currently able to do this?